# @Pattern with Unicode script \\p{L}* doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, bean-validation, character-properties

I have problem with 
javax.validation.constraints.Pattern @Pattern validation.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "\\p{L}*", message = "Msg")
private String name;
```

When I'm trying to input any text it doesn't work.

When I used:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]*", message = "Msg")
```

It works great with non latin characters.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: What text do you type? Note that the pattern here is anchored, you may only type letters. To allow, e.g. spaces, too, use `[\\p{L}\\s]*`.

Comment: I'm typing in froms text and validator returns me validation error.

Comment: When I use: 'regexp = "[a-zA-Z]*' it works good with: "abc" but It doesn't work with Latin characters.

Comment: I'm trying with: "abc" "ąść"

Comment: What if you use `regexp = "(?U)\\p{L}*"`?

Comment: So you're saying that with `\\p{L}*`, `abc` is rejected?

Comment: @assylias yes, it's rejected

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah. It's work. Thank you. What does it mean: (?U)

Comment: I have posted the suggestion as an answer with explanation and a reference link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `\p{L}` pattern Unicode aware with the [**`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

> Enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes.

Since you are using the string pattern, you may use the inline (embedded) flag variant, `(?U)`:

```
regexp = "(?U)\\p{L}*"
```